# Configured compileSdkVersion is invalid

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, gluon-desktop

Hello I am having problem building or creating an apk file on this gluon project. I follow the step in building the project on this site http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/3.0.0/#_android_2. I am a total newbie on this framework. Please help

Executing: gradle :android

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Configured compileSdkVersion is invalid: 21 (C:/Users/flashery/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platforms/android-21

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.421 secs



Build failure (see the Notifications window for stacktrace): gradle :android



Issue 1
--------

  Requested project: C:\Users\flashery\Documents\NetBeansProjects\GluonApplication

  Stack trace:
    org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip'.
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:72)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask.runBuild(AsyncGradleTask.java:369)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask.doGradleTasksWithProgressIgnoreTaskDefCancel(AsyncGradleTask.java:492)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask.doGradleTasksWithProgressIgnoreTaskDefCancel(AsyncGradleTask.java:402)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask.doGradleTasksWithProgress(AsyncGradleTask.java:393)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask.access$400(AsyncGradleTask.java:84)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.AsyncGradleTask$BuildExecutionItem$1.run(AsyncGradleTask.java:775)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.runBlockingGradleTask(GradleDaemonManager.java:51)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.access$200(GradleDaemonManager.java:22)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager$2.execute(GradleDaemonManager.java:128)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$FunctionWrapper.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:270)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$TaskOfAbstractExecutor.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:340)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.Tasks$RunOnceCancelableTask.execute(Tasks.java:342)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor$ThreadPoolTaskExecutorImpl$QueuedItem.runTask(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:1213)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor$ThreadPoolTaskExecutorImpl$Worker.executeTask(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:1049)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor$ThreadPoolTaskExecutorImpl$Worker.run(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:1179)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor$ThreadPoolTaskExecutorImpl$Worker$1.run(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:998)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Configured compileSdkVersion is invalid: 21 (C:/Users/flashery/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platforms/android-21
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
        at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:101)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Configured compileSdkVersion is invalid: 21 (C:/Users/flashery/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platforms/android-21
        at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.plugin.android.AndroidExtension.validate(AndroidExtension.groovy:106)
        at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.plugin.android.AndroidExtension$validate.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.plugin.JFXMobilePlugin.configureAndroid(JFXMobilePlugin.groovy:556)
        at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.plugin.JFXMobilePlugin.this$2$configureAndroid(JFXMobilePlugin.groovy)
        at org.javafxports.jfxmobile.plugin.JFXMobilePlugin$_apply_closure5.doCall(JFXMobilePlugin.groovy:213)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.graphPopulated(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:108)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        ... 42 more
```

Gradle build file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:3.0.0'

    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-android:3.0.0'
    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-ios:3.0.0'
    desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:3.0.0'
}

jfxmobile {

    javafxportsVersion = '8.60.7'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = '21'
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = 'C:/Users/flashery/AppData/Local/Android/sdk'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'io.datafx.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` file? Have you set `ANDROID_HOME`?  What android sdk do you have installed (platforms 21, 22, 23)?

Comment: You don't need to set the sdk version parameter on your build file unless you want to specifically set it to that level. In that case, you need to install it, sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've totally solved it, it was funny i had the same problem but take a look:

[You should install those packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU1Ew.png)

Go to android studio(I did it this way but I think theres no need for android studio) Create a project go to preferences then appearance and behaviour after that system settings next to that Android SDK then Launch Standalone SDK manager, then be sure (since the question is from today) that you select on obsolete packages, then install what I put in the image and try again, I found this info from a spanish written web

Comment: I am installing what you have in the picture. But I couldn't see the "Android support library" on SDK Manager

Comment: Thanks I have successfully build my app. Can you help me with another problem I have? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538903/couldnt-run-javafx-port-application-on-genymotion-with-flash-arm-trnaslation

Comment: yes sure, the android support library is an obsolete library I think so just click on obsolete and that will display all that stuff

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the android support libraries, which is a requirement to this as well as the build tools and the sdk

Comment: I am installing the packages. But I couldn't see the "Android support library" on SDK Manager